# How do I restore a SQL backup, while excluding a specific table?

Tags: mysql, restore

How do I exclude a specific table during a SQL backup RESTORE operation?

My question is specific to restoring a backup sql file.

I am using `Putty` and `bash` server.

Comment: What engine? MySQL? Do you mean "restore, but don't overwrite current table" or "I don't want this table after restore"?

Comment: @myskny: which db server you are using it it mysql..?

Comment: putty and bash eliminate SQL Server as a possible suspect.

Answer (score 3):

You don't.  You restore the backup as a new DB, drop the unwanted table from it, then take a new backup of this working DB.